# Why does adding "offline_access" invalidate MS Graph scope and how do I otherwise get a refresh token?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I'm trying to request an access token and a refresh token from Microsoft Graph, but adding "offline_access" to the scope makes the scope invalid.

This is for a service where a user gives us access to an Outlook Calendar once and after that the service checks their calendar every 20 minutes for events. I have managed to get consent and pull data when requesting access to "User.Read" and "`Calendars.Read`", but when I add "`offline_access`" I get the message `The provided resource value for the input parameter 'scope' is not valid.`

I have an array with the permissions I want

```java
private static final String[] ACCESS_PERMISSIONS = {
            "https://graph.microsoft.com/User.Read",
            "https://graph.microsoft.com/Calendars.Read",
            "https://graph.microsoft.com/offline_access",
    };
```

and then combine and encode them

```java
String encodedScope = URLEncoder.encode(
Arrays.stream(ACCESS_PERMISSIONS)
.reduce(
(a,b) -> a + " " + b)
.get(), "UTF-8").replace("+","%20");
```

which results in the string `https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com%2FUser.Read%20https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com%2FCalendars.Read%20https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com%2Foffline_access`
Then I request the tokens

```java
String appId = "client_id=" + clientID;
String scope = "&scope=" + encodedScope;
String authCode = "&code=" + code;
String redirect = "&redirect_uri=" + redirectUri;
String grantType = "&grant_type=authorization_code";
String secret = "&client_secret=" + clientSecret;

String data = appId + scope + authCode + redirect + grantType + secret;

// Create POST request
URL url = new URL(postUrl);
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

// Configure request
connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
connection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
connection.setDoOutput(true);

// Send data
OutputStream os = connection.getOutputStream();
byte[] inputBytes = data.getBytes(ENCODING);
os.write(inputBytes, 0, inputBytes.length); // Bytes, Offset, Length
```

The final link then looks like

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?
client_id=[CLIENT ID]
&response_type=code
&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2Fsport%2Fauth%2Foutlook
&response_mode=query
&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com%2FUser.Read%20https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com%2FCalendars.Read%20https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com%2Foffline_access
&state=2737
```

I would expect this to return an access token and a refresh token, but as previously mentioned I get the message that the resource value for the scope is not valid.

It is essential for the service to be able to refresh the tokens as it should run about a year without intervention.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The scope isn't `https://graph.microsoft.com/offline_access`, it is simply `offline_access`. Offline Access is a special AAD scope that tells it to return a Refresh Token, it isn't a Microsoft Graph scope.

You can actually drop `https://graph.microsoft.com/` across the board. The only time you need to specify the FQDN is when you're requesting the default set of scopes from the app registration (i.e. `https://graph.microsoft.com/.default`) but that is generally only used when you're using App-Only/Daemon authentication flow (Client Credentials).